# Not able to get webparts on a site page in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

Using the below code using CSOM, I'm not able to fetch the webparts of a page in Sharepoint.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File oFile = this._ClientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(myurl );
                LimitedWebPartManager limitedWebPartManager = oFile.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);
                this._ClientContext.Load(limitedWebPartManager.WebParts,
                 wps => wps.Include(
                 wp => wp.WebPart.Title,
                 wp => wp.Id,
                 wp => wp.WebPart.ExportMode,
                 wp => wp.WebPart.TitleUrl,
                 wp => wp.WebPart.Properties
                 ));
                this._ClientContext.Load(limitedWebPartManager.WebParts);
                this._ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                var areItemsavail = limitedWebPartManager.WebParts.AreItemsAvailable;
                var webpartcount = limitedWebPartManager.WebParts.Count;
```

The `areItemsavail` above shows `true`, while the `webpartcount` shows the value `0`.
There are lot of webparts available on the dedicated page.
Is there any way to fetch/get the `webparts` on a Sharepoint Site Page using CSOM ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which type of page you created?

webpart page:

[image]

publishing page:

[image]

not for modern page(site page)
[image]

Comment: For the modern page (communication site). Can we get the same for modern pages ?

Comment: Check https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-all-client-side-webparts-from-a-sharepoint-modern-page-using-pnp-core-how-to-extract-modern-page-webparts-using-pnp-core for modern page.